# Regex to match newline in Google Sheets using a formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I have a block of text

```
➤ What is your Linkedin profile URL if you have not connected with on Linkedin?: test url
another
yet another

Need to make changes to this event?
```

Where I need to extract the text

```
**EXPECTED RESULT:**
test url
another
yet another
```

I have tried with

```
=trim(REGEXEXTRACT($C$4,"\n.*➤ What is your Linkedin profile URL if you have not connected with on Linkedin\?\:(.*)Need to make changes to event\?"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?s)➤\s+What\s+is\s+your\s+Linkedin\s+profile\s+URL\s+if\s+you\s+have\s+not\s+connected\s+with\s+on\s+Linkedin\?:(.*)Need\s+to\s+make\s+changes\s+to\s+this\s+event\?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gCpcAj/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a singleline modifier flag that makes a `.` match any line break chars
- `➤\s+` - `➤` and one or more whitespace chars
- `What\s+is\s+your\s+Linkedin\s+profile\s+URL\s+if\s+you\s+have\s+not\s+connected\s+with\s+on\s+Linkedin\?:` - a literal `What is your Linkedin profile URL if you have not connected with on Linkedin?:` string with any one or more whitespaces between the words
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `Need\s+to\s+make\s+changes\s+to\s+this\s+event\?` - a literal `Need to make changes to this event?` with  with any one or more whitespaces between the words.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), FILTER(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), " "), " "), 
                 ISURL(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), " "), " "))))
```

[image]